# Dialog Box from DT-DD

Tags: php, jquery, jquery-ui

I have a long list of items that are in the DT / DD format.  Here is my PHP

```
foreach($allnews as $row){
 $row->subject = ucwords($row->subject); 
echo "<dt class=\"row\">$row->date -> $row->subject </dt>";
echo "<dd class=\"show\">$row->news</dd>";
}
```

Here is my Jquery;

```
$(function(){
   $('.show').hide(); //hide the DD
   $('.row').click(function(){
        $('.show').dialog({
            width: 400,
            stack: false,
            height: 500               
        });    
    });      
 });
```

I am going to make this into a modal when I solve my problem.  And my problem is this: **When I click on one of my DT's I do get the dialog box (opens the DD and displays correctly).  However I get the dialog box for every single item that comes out of the database.  I want just the row that I click to open up into a dialog box or soon to be a modal**

I know that if I use "this" it will probably select just one row.  But where do I use it?
I will have no problem making it into a modal, I just want to know how to choose just the row I click

thank you in advance

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The selectors are global.  In your click function,

```
$('.show').dialog(...)
```

will do exactly what you are seeing.  Activate for all elements with the `$('.show')` class.  Instead, you want to work within the context of the element you clicked.  For example

```
$('.row').click(function() {
    $(this).next('.show').dialog(...);
}
```

This will set the currently clicked `'.row'` as your `this` element and then find the next element (sibling), confirm that it matches the `'.show'` selector, and then run the dialog.

JSFiddle Demonstration: http://jsfiddle.net/ayv6U/

Comment: yes that works perfectly.  I see that your use of "this" defines that show is what is being pointed at.  Thank you very much

Comment: Technically, `this` refers to the `.row` and then I use your HTML structure to find the next sibling.  If you change your structure, this code wouldn't work.  For example, if you put something between the DT and DD.  `next()` will only grab the immediately following sibling.  See alternatives here: http://api.jquery.com/category/traversing/tree-traversal/

Comment: I see, dd being the next child of dt(row)

Comment: Next Sibling :)  The difference is important - you could wrap each DT/DD pair in another element and use that parent-child relationship, too.  Play around with the jQuery Traversal functions and you'll get a better idea of how it all works.